# OLS estimator for beta

Tags: least-squares, estimators

I have a question that i don't really understand. I'm pretty sure its really easy but i just can't think right now, and if anyone could help me i'd really appreciate it.

Consider the following regression model with one control variable  = 0 + 11 +  Obtain the OLS estimators for ̂ 0 and ̂ 1 (Hint: Remember that you have to minimize the sum of squared residuals.)

Thanks a lot everyone.

Comment: Welcome to this site ! If this homework, you should add the [tag:self-study] tag and show us what you have done and where you are stuck with this.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=least+squares+formula for links to hundreds of related posts.